# storing PIG log files in a separate folder

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to save my PIG log files (the ones that generate after an unsuccessful execution) to another folder (say the Desktop). It is currently being saved in the Documents folder and I have almost 100 - 150 of them just lying around.

I'm on an Ubuntu environment, and doing this locally (not on HDInsight, or on a Cloudera VM).

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default pig keeps the log files in the current working directory. If you want to specify a different directory you can do that by passing -l option.

In mapreduce mode:

```
pig -l /log/path
```

In local mode:

```
pig -x local -l /log/path
```

Answer (score 2):

It keeps all error log files in current working directory. If you ant to save them in separate folders, you should open $PIG_HOME/conf/pig.propertes file and update value of pig.logfile paramater.